# Help finding this set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions

Lets define the following:

Let A be a set. A is innumerable if and only if there exists a bijective function from A to $\mathbb{N}$

Proof that there exists an innumerable set $B \subseteq \mathcal P \left({\mathbb{N}}\right)$ such that it has the following properties:

1) $X\cap Y =\emptyset$ for all $X,Y \in B$ such that $X \neq Y$

2) $\mathbb{N}= \bigcup B$

3) All elements of B are innumerable.

Any help is appreciated. I don´t know how to find this set ...

Answer (score 1):

For $n=0,1,\ldots$, let $B_n = \{2^{n}(2k+1): k =0,1,\ldots \}$. Then your set $B = \{ B_n: n =0,1,\ldots\}$. The sets are disjoint and cover $\mathbb{N}$, as $m \in B_n$ iff it has exactly $n$ factors $2$ in its prime decomposition.

(you might want to add $0$ to $B_0$, if $0 \in \mathbb{N}$ (opinions differ), otherwise we'd miss it in $\cup_n B_n$.)

Answer (score 0):

Form the following diagram of all the natural numbers:

$
.\\
.\\
21~~...\\
11~~20 ~ ...\\
10~~12~~19 ~...\\
4~~~~9~~~~13~~18 ...\\
3~~~~5~~~~8~~~14~~17 ...\\
1~~~~2~~~~6~~~~7~~~15~~~16 ...$

Now let

$a_1 = \{1,2,6,7,15,...\}\\
a_2 = \{3,5,8,14,17,...\}\\
a_3 = \{4,9,13,18,...\}$

and so on. Let $B = \{a_1,a_2,...\}$. Then $B$ is innumerable, all the elements of $B$ are disjunct (and innumerable) and covers all the natural numbers by construction.